# How to provide a cmake package (aka Config.cmake) that supports static linking

Tags: cmake, static-linking

Most questions on StackOverflow are users who want to statically link against some library.  Suppose I'm a library author, and I'm trying to define a `Config.cmake` that will allow my users to choose between dynamically and statically linking against my library. How am I supposed to structure this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a variable like `MY_LIBRARY_LINK_STATIC` and depending on the value (`true` for static linking, `false` for dynamic) decide what type to use.

Comment: But it's not as simple as this, right? When I make a shared library, I get to assume the built in dynamic dependencies in the foo.so are good enough to specify the transitive dependencies. With static linking, I have to publish the transitive dependencies, because they all need to be included in the linker line.